# Extracting values from ployshape class

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

[image]

I have a .mat file in which there are 192 polyshape and in each polyshape there is a matrix of [16*2] double

I want to extract all those [16*2] double values from each polyshape and store it into .csv file

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [ask]. Also, how are these polyshapes stored in the MAT file? As separate variables, in a cell array, ...?

Comment: @Cris Luengo they're stored as a cell array

Comment: Don't tell me, [edit] your question so that people understand what you're after and can give you a useful answer. I recommend that you include code that creates a demonstration MAT-file, or at least the result of loading that MAT-file back into MATLAB, so that people can actually try out proposed solutions and see that they work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to concatenate all the vertices matrices and use 'writematrix' function to write a double matrix into a CSV file. I assume that there is a variable named 'polyshapes' which is an array of all the 192 polyshape data you have. Then you can run the following.

```
a = [];
for i = 1:192 % Loop to concatenate
    a = [a; polyshapes(i).Vertices];
end
writematrix(a,'filename.csv');
```

Regards,
Zenin